# Extracting $t_0$ from $4g_0(x-g_0t_0)+4g_1(y-g_1t_0)+2(g_1(x-g_0t_0)+g_0(y-g_1t_0))+20g_0+10g_1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I need to extract $t_0$ from this formula
$$4g_0(x-g_0t_0)+4g_1(y-g_1t_0)+2\left(\,g_1(x-g_0t_0)+g_0(y-g_1t_0)\,\right)+20g_0+10g_1 = 0$$
as a symbol (ex, $ax+b=c \to x=(c-b)/a$).

Can someone help me somehow? I have no idea how to do that.

(I'm first time on this site.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please use Mathjax to typeset your question, here's a handy reference guide that covers all the basics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Wr0ng: I formatted your formula, taking the liberty of reducing visual clutter by replacing your `grad[n]` terms with $g_n$, as well as removing some unnecessary parentheses. ... In any case, your formula is not an *equation* (there's no "$=$"), so "extracting" (ie, solving-for) $t_0$ doesn't make sense. Is something missing?

Comment: @Blue I forgot to equalize with 0 the entire formula

Comment: Expand and collect $t_0$
$$\left(-4 g_0^2-4 g_1 g_0-4 g_1^2\right) t_0+4 g_0 x+2 g_1 x+2 g_0 y+4 g_1 y+20 g_0+10 g_1=0$$
then solve
$$t_0=\frac{2 g_0 x+g_1 x+g_0 y+2 g_1 y+10 g_0+5 g_1}{2 \left(g_0^2+g_1 g_0+g_1^2\right)}$$